# Translate Keras functional API to PyTorch nn.Module - Conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I'm trying to translate the following Inception code from tutorial in Keras functional API ([link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/28/3-ways-to-create-a-keras-model-with-tensorflow-2-0-sequential-functional-and-model-subclassing/)) to PyTorch `nn.Module`:

```
    def conv_module(x, K, kX, kY, stride, chanDim, padding="same"):
        # define a CONV => BN => RELU pattern
        x = Conv2D(K, (kX, kY), strides=stride, padding=padding)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)
        # return the block
        return x


    def inception_module(x, numK1x1, numK3x3, chanDim):
        # define two CONV modules, then concatenate across the
        # channel dimension
        conv_1x1 = conv_module(x, numK1x1, 1, 1, (1, 1), chanDim)
        conv_3x3 = conv_module(x, numK3x3, 3, 3, (1, 1), chanDim)
        x = concatenate([conv_1x1, conv_3x3], axis=chanDim)
        # return the block
        return x
```

I'm having trouble translating the `Conv2D`. If I understand correctly:

1. There is no `in_features` in Keras - how should I represent it in PyTorch?
2. Keras `filters` is PyTorch `out_features`
3. `kernel_size`, `stride` and `padding` are the same (maybe a few options for `padding` are called differently)

Do I understand this correctly? If so, what should I do with `in_features`? My code so far:

```
class BasicConv2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            in_channels: int,
            out_channels: int,
            kernel_size: int,
            stride: int
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels,
                              out_channels,
                              kernel_size=kernel_size,
                              stride=stride)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels, eps=0.001)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x

class Inception(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            in_channels: int,
            num_1x1_filters: int,
            num_3x3_filters: int,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # how to fill this further?
        self.conv_1d = BasicConv2d(
            num_1x1_filters,
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct for the most part. The `in_channels` parameter in `Con2d` corresponds to the no. of output channels from the previous layer. If `Conv2d` is the first layer, the `in_channels` correspond to the no. of channels in your image. It will be 1 for a Grayscale image and 3 for an RGB image.

But I'm not sure how you could concat the two BasicConv2d outputs.

Fixing batch_size as 1, assume that the image size is `256*256` and `out_channels` for `conv1x1` is 64. This would output a tensor of shape `torch.Size([1, 64, 256, 256])`. Assuming `out_channels` of the `conv3x3` as 32, this layer would output a tensor of shape `torch.Size([1, 32, 254, 254])`. We will not be able to concat these two tensors without some trick, such as using `padding=1` for the `conv3x3` alone as this would produce an output of shape `torch.Size([1, 32, 256, 256])` and therefore we would be able to concat.

Comment: Did you mean `torch.size([1, 32, 256, 256])` in the `conv3x3` output shape? Because I need to stack `[1, 64, 256, 256]` from the `conv1x1` and `[1, 32, 256, 256` from the `conv3x3` in the channels dimension, i.e. "Concat in channels" from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03530.pdf (the tutorial implements this paper in Keras, I want to do it in PyTorch). I think I should be able to stack it this way along `dim=1`.

Comment: Also PyTorch docs for `torch.cat()` state that "All tensors must either have the same shape (except in the concatenating dimension)", which would mean that this will work for stacking channels AFAIK.

Comment: I didn't mean `torch.size([1, 32, 256, 256])` because this is not the expected output from a `3x3 convolution`.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, it makes sense. So I will just pad this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `BasicConv2d` is fine, here is the code of Inception module.

```
class Inception(nn.Module):
def __init__(
        self,
        in_channels: int,
        num_1x1_filters: int,
        num_3x3_filters: int,
) -> None:
    super().__init__()
    # how to fill this further?
    self.conv1 = BasicConv2d(in_channels, num_1x1_filters, 1,1)
    self.conv3 = BasicConv2d(in_channels, num_3x3_filters, 3,1)
def forward(self,x):
    conv1_out = self.conv1(x)
    conv3_out = self.conv3(x)
    x = torch.cat([conv1_out, conv3_out],)
    return x
```

You need define two basic conv layers, and use them in the forward pass with same input separately.
As @planet_pluto pointed, you can't concatenate two feature maps have different size. you can choose a better `stride`, `padding` to construct two feature maps with same size, alternatively, do upsampling or downsampling before you concatenate them.